# Jmeter - how to handle changing parameters? CSV config file is only with fixed set of parameters

Tags: jmeter

My webservice url takes varying parameters - 
1) var1, 
2)var1 and var2. 
3) var1 and var2. 
4) var1, var2 and var3

CSV config file can take only fixed number and kind of variable.

Can someone please guide to parameterize in one script. I am new to Jmeter

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Jmeter and Performance testing!!!!

You should be more specific about your problems!!! I'm Not sure about what are your requirements but let me guess one thing that you need to parameterize your scripts!!

If it is the requirement, you can try with the [User Parameters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters).

You can also look this sample image:

[image]